# Is there an equivalent of RoundHalfUp for NSDecimalNumber ?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there an **equivalent** to `NSNumberFormatterRoundingMode.RoundHalfUp` when doing calculations using `NSDecimalNumber` ?

Because from what I can see `NSDecimalNumber` accepts only 4 `NSRoundingModes` (via `NSDecimalNumberHandler`) :

```
enum NSRoundingMode : UInt {
  case RoundPlain
  case RoundDown
  case RoundUp
  case RoundBankers
}
```

Comment: You can always multiply by 2, round up, and then divide by 2 to get same result.

Comment: You mean multiply by a 100, round up then divide by a 100 ?

Comment: I misunderstood the question, thought you're talking about _rounding to nearest 0.5_. Sorry!

Answer (score -1):

According to [NSNumberFormatterRoundingMode Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enum/c:@E@NSNumberFormatterRoundingMode):

> NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp
>
> Round towards the nearest integer, or away from zero if equidistant.

Meaning 1.5 will round to 2 and -1.5 will round to -2 as -2 if farther away from 0 than -1.

According to NSRoundingMode - [NSDecimalNumberBehaviors Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSDecimalNumberBehaviors_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enum/c:@E@NSRoundingMode):

> NSRoundPlain
>
> Round to the closest possible return value; when caught halfway between two positive numbers, round up; when caught between two
>   negative numbers, round down.

They give the example 1.25 will round to 1.3 and -1.35 will round to -1.4.

They are functionally equivalent. If you want the exact same behavior set roundingMode to NSRoundMode.RoundPlain and scale to 0.